# jquery-datatables individual column searching (select inputs) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I use datatables.js and I want to use individual column searching (select inputs) but it doesn,t work. The table is shown but without the select inputs below the columns... Has anybody an idea? Any hint would be helpful

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
//use json and create dynamic table   
//http://jsperf.com/table-rows-20120430/3
var colData = [" ", "Tool Name", "Producer", "Usability"];
var rowData = [["A","Tool1", "Producer1", "7"],
              ["B","Tool2","Producer2","4"],
              ["C","Tool3", "Producer3","2"]];
 var data = {"Cols":colData, "Rows":rowData};`

var table = $('<table/>').attr("id", "userquerytable").addClass("display").attr("cellspacing", "0").attr("width", "100%");




var tr = $('<tr/>');
table.append('<thead>').children('thead').append(tr);

for (var i=0; i< data.Cols.length; i++) {
  tr.append('<td>'+data.Cols[i]+'</td>'); 
}

for(var r=0; r < data.Rows.length; r++){   
    var tr = $('<tr/>');
    table.append(tr);  
    //loop through cols for each row...
    for(var c=0; c < data.Cols.length; c++){
        tr.append('<td>'+data.Rows[r][c]+'</td>');   
    }
}

$('#userquerytable-container').table({
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().column().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    }
});
```

} );

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you move to the latest DataTable version (1.10).  If you are using this library there really should be no reason for you to have manually construct the whole table.  That is what this library is for.